# Javascript replace exact match string

Tags: javascript

I have the following

var string = '1,7,12,15,16,29';

if I just want to replace the number 1, i will use the following

```
removeStr(1);

 function removeStr(str1)
        {  
            var string = '1,7,12,15,16,29';
            var newstr = string.replace(str1, '');
            alert('new val is ' + newstr);
        }
```

But doing this, will end up removing the number 1 in 12,15,16.

How do I just remove the exact match **1** in this example.

Thanks

Comment: "*But doing this, will end up removing the number 1 in 12,15,16.*" - will it? I'm pretty sure that, in your posted code, it'll only remove the first occurrence of the `"1"` character.

Comment: Your code produces `new val is ,7,12,15,16,29`. `replace` only replaces the first match

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use boundaries (`\b`) in a regexp that to match a whole word only.  Changed your test string to one where your question would be applicable

```js
function removeStr(str1)
{  
  var string = '11,71,12,1,16,21';
  var newstr = string.replace(new RegExp("\\b"+str1+"\\b"), "");
  console.log('new val is ' + newstr);
}

removeStr("1");
```

Comment: this works definitely, but dont know why? `\b` is the word boundary right?

Comment: Yes, `\b` is a word boundary, but it matches a position - not any actual characters.  The match returned the example string from `"\b1\b"` is just `"1"`.  `12`, `15` and `16` are not matched because there is only a `\b` before the `1`, not after.

Comment: this will work only on english language

Comment: @HouzayfaRifai this is a limitation of RegEx.  But since this incarnation of Stack Overflow is [English only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange), I'm not sure why you would expect any different.  There is however [another answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange) that deals with this that might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function replaceOne(str1, str2){
    var arr = str2.split(",");

    var newStr = "";

    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i]!=str1){
            newStr = (newStr=="")?arr[i]:newStr+","+arr[i];
        }
    }

    console.log(newStr);
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of how this code helps the OP. Code without explanation does not help future visitors. Also, take a look at [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/215552) on the FAQ.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to do it on strings.
you might consider to make it an array

```js
var string = '1,7,12,15,16,29';
var arr=string.split(",");
var newArr=arr.splice("1");
string=newArr.join(",");
console.log(string);
```

Hope this helps